# Is it less secure to use a passphrase-removed key with apache?

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl

I have a simple website with an ssl certificate and I noticed that when I would reboot apache was asking for the passphrase (causing the server to halt essentially).

I did the following to remove it (fixing my issue w/ the reboot)

> openssl rsa -in foo.key -out foo.key.nopass

The question I have is, does this in any way reduce the effectiveness of my ssl cert?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In normal operation (ie, with an encrypted private key), the private key is known to the running webserver, but isn't present on-disc.  In order to get a copy of the private key, an attacker would have to subvert the running webserver.

If you leave the private key constantly decrypted on-disc, then (assuming you have the permissions set tightly) an attacker needs only to subvert the file system.

But as you've observed, there is a cost to leaving the key encrypted on-disc: unattended restarts aren't possible.  Only you can say whether the additional security afforded by leaving the key encrypted on-disc justifies the additional cost.

For myself, I suspect that anyone who can subvert file system protections can probably read your web server's memory anyway (think `/proc/kcore`), and thus the difficulty of extracting the decrypted key from the memory map of the running server is the only additional protection afforded by encrypting the key.  I tend to assume attackers are intelligent, so that makes the additional security fairly small.